# Cannot run ipython as a command using fabric

Tags: python, ipython, fabric

I can use Fabric fine to run commands on the server.

This command is not working however

> run(u'ipython profile create myprofile')

it returns this error

> Warning: run() received nonzero return code 127 while executing 'ipython profile create myprofile'!

Am I doing something wrong. Thanx.

Comment: Can you log in on that server and issue a command manually? If so, are there any errors reported?

Comment: Specifically, _that_ command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because fabric couldn't find the `ipython` command. If a command is not found 127 is returned from OS.

I believe you dont have ipython installed or its not installed in the `$PATH` that is set for fabric. If you are using virtual environment I suggest you use the absolute path for both python and ipython. Something like

```
run('/virtual-env/bin/python /virtual-env/bin/ipython profile create myprofile')
```

You can check which paths are in use by `run('echo $PATH')`

Comment: Yes, because I used Anaconda distro, the folders structure is different...just added it to the path, and it worked. Thanks!